# Why does node_modules have an underscore but package-lock.json has a hyphen?

Tags: node.js, npm

Since they're both created by `npm install`, it seems inconsistent.

Comment: Could be because node_modules is a folder and package-lock.json is a file.

Comment: Over what people break their mind...